# Pickle only saving last pair of inputs from a list of several pairs of user inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having an issue where the pickle module is only saving the last pair of inputs that the user inputted.

How can I make it so that the pickle module saves every pair of inputs (a pair of a question and answer) not just the last one that was inputted?

```
import pickle
import random
import os
os.system('cls')

    n = input("How many questions do you have? : ")
    vvff = list()

    for i in range(0, int(n)):
        v = input("Enter question : ")
        while True:
            f = input("Enter answer ((true) or (false)) : ")
            if f.lower() in ('true', 'false'):
                    break
            else:
                print("Invalid answer")
    for i in range(0, int(n)):
            vf = {"question": v, "answer": f}
            vvff.append(vf)

    question_vff = input("Would you like to save (yes or  no)")
    if (question_vff == 'yes'):
            pickle.dump(vvff, open("Savequestionandanswerlist.dat", "wb"))
            pickle.dump(n, open("Savequestionamount.dat", "wb"))
            print("Saved!")
    if (question_vff == 'no'):
            print ("Please save to use this information,")
```

Comment: Did you mess up the indentation in copy/pasting your code? Because this will just error.

Comment: @jonrshape No I did not

Comment: Your first loop prompts the user for `v` and `f`, `n` times - each time overwriting the last pair of values.  Your second loop then appends those values (the final ones) to a list, `n` times.  In other words, `pickle` has absolutely nothing to do with your problem - you failed to save more than a single pair of values, from the very start.  You need a *single* loop, that appends each pair to the list as it is generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not adding the questions and answers in your main loop. When you do a loop outside of your main one, the variables `v` and `f` are set to the last question and answer that was issued. Just add them to your list when you know you have them:

```
    ...
    for i in range(0, int(n)):
        v = input("Enter question : ")
        while True:
            f = input("Enter answer ((true) or (false)) : ")
            if f.lower() in ('true', 'false'):
                # We have our question, along with a valid answer so add them to our list!
                vf = {"question": v, "answer": f}
                vvff.append(vf)
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid answer")

    question_vff = input("Would you like to save (yes or  no)")
    ...
```